# ActionCable issues on app upgraded to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

ActionCable is not working on my app that I just upgraded to Rails 5.0.1.
I generated a channel with `rails g channel`.

When I run the server I don't see any line in the log that indicates ActionCable is doing anything. On the client side I get `App is not defined`

I created a new app with `rails new` and ActionCable works fine in it. I compared all the relevant files in and they look the same in both apps.

Are there some gems that I need to install in my upgraded app that would be installed by default in a new Rails 5 app? I checked and I have actioncable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem was that `cable.js` was not included in `application.js` because I have my javascript files included explicitly by name and forgot to add cable.

Don't know if this Q&A will help anyone else, but if it does....

Comment: Yes. Exactly @Life4ants. This is a great Q&A. You should accept your answer and I should thank you for your help !!! Fabrizio Bertoglio